# How to check the count of the specific image occurring in a JSON

Tags: json, image, count, appcelerator

I am trying to increase the count if the value of the image is "/images/apps/urgent-marker.png". But the value of the count still remains 0.

```
var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].statusImageId.image === "/images/apps/urgent-marker.png"){
            log.trace("titleForPendingTasksLabel   >>>  i  >>>",i);
            count = count + 1;
            log.trace("count is >>> ",count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should also post the JSON file. It may be simply that there is no image with this name.

Comment: without seeing what is contained in  `data` we can't say. The code looks fine on the face of it, but perhaps the data is not structured as per the way you're trying to access it, or the value simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, is it a JSON object, or is it the views array in the **data** variable.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is to use == in place of === .... though it doesn't make sense but can try it for once.. else provide the value of **data** variable.